# C# Why can I not add a hashset typed to a subclass to a hashset typed to its superclass

Tags: c#, generics, collections, hashset

Why do I get a compile error in the following code (see line with comment)?

```
    public void Test()
    {
        HashSet<HashSet<Animal>> setWithSets = new HashSet<HashSet<Animal>>();
        HashSet<Cat> cats = new HashSet<Cat>();
        setWithSets.Add(cats); // Compile error
    }

    private class Animal { }

    private class Cat : Animal { }
```

VS2012 gives me two errors, the first one the important one:

- Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Expenses.Tests.TestDb.SetTest.Cat>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Expenses.Tests.TestDb.SetTest.Animal>'
- Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Expenses.Tests.TestDb.SetTest.Animal>>.Add(System.Collections.Generic.HashSet)' has some invalid arguments

My question is: Why can I not add "cats" to the "setWithSets"?

Comment: You're looking at Generic Covariance, and you might wanna check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0 or this article (it's using the same objects as you actually) -> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/10/28/linq-farm-covariance-and-contravariance-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will check them out. I also found another post that might make this post duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314006/how-do-you-manage-a-c-sharp-generics-class-where-the-type-is-a-container-of-a-ba?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To better understand why this is not allowed, consider the following program.

The line `setOfSets.First().Add(new Dog());` is acceptable to the compiler, because a collection of animals can surely hold an instance of `Dog`. The problem is that the first collection of animals in the collection is a collection of `Cat` instances, and `Dog` does not extend `Cat`.

```
class Animal { }
class Cat : Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // This is a collection of collections of animals.
        HashSet<HashSet<Animal>> setOfSets = new HashSet<HashSet<Animal>>();

        // Here, we add a collection of cats to that collection.
        HashSet<Cat> cats = new HashSet<Cat>();
        setOfSets.Add(cats);

        // And here, we add a dog to the collection of cats. Sorry, kitty!
        setOfSets.First().Add(new Dog());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to do the same thing with apples and bananas :)

Comment: Funny thing languages like Java support covariance in arrays, which causes some runtime checks to prevent these type of thing, impacting the performance

Comment: Marking this as 'answer', as it simple and clearly illustrates the problem with my thinking. However, I really appreciacte the other follow-ups, as they give me deeper insight in the subject.

Comment: @RicardoRodrigues .NET also has this "crazy" covariance of array types, leading to type checks at all writes, and same performance hit. It's been like that ever since .NET 1 (that is before generics).

Answer (score 7):

Even if `Cat` derives from `Animal`, it is not true that `HashSet<Cat>` derives from `HashSet<Animal>`. (The only base class of `HashSet<Anything>` is the `object` class.)

To get the behavior you want, the `HashSet<T>` generic type would need to be ***covariant*** in its type parameter `T`. But it is not, for two reasons:

1. In C#, only generic interfaces and generic delegate types can be co- or contravariant. `HashSet<>` is a class.
2. You can not only read from a `HashSet<>`, you can also ***add*** to it (and do other things). Therefore covariance is logically impossible. Or else one would be able to regard a `HashSet<Cat>` as a `HashSet<Animal>` and then add a `Dog` to it. But a set of cats does not allow dogs.

If you changed `HashSet<T>` into for example `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` (see .NET 4.5 [documentation: `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542.aspx)), things would work because the latter type (1) is an interface, (2) allows only reads, and (3) has therefore premitted a marking "I'm covariant in `T`" which the authors of the type decided to apply.

Answer (score 5):

You get a compiler error, because the type constructor of HashSet is **invariant**.

For an explanation of the term invariant, have a look at [Covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: I wouldn't say the _constructor_ was invariant; I would say the class (or type) is invariant (in `T`).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I fixed the wording to match the wiki article.

Comment: This would be the correct answer if you changed the phrasing a little, it's not the constructor of HashSet that is invariant, it's HashSet itself in T.
Just to add some more info, in order for this to be possible, HashSet<T> would have to be covariant in its type parameter T, like IEnumerable<T> is since .NET 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Because `HashSet<Cat>` does not derive from `HashSet<Animal>`, which is required for what you want to do.

What you *can* do is add a `Cat` to a `HashSet<Animal>`, because `Cat` derives from `Animal`
What you *cannot* do is add a `HashSet<Cat>` to a `HashSet<HashSet<Animal>>`

You probably thought you could use covariance, which allows you to do this:

```
IEnumerable<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = cats;
```

This works because this is the interface declaration for IEnumerable:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

Notice the 'out T'? That's covariance. It basically allows you to have inheritance-like behavior on generically-typed classes. Note that you can only declare covariance on interfaces. Now let's look at ISet, the interface that HashSet implements:

```
public interface ISet<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see, no 'out' keyword. That means you can't do this:

```
ISet<Cat> cats = new HashSet<Cat>();
ISet<Animal> animals = cats;
```